# Need help converting InfluxQL query to InfluxDB2 Flux

Tags: influxdb, influxql, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I’m trying to figure out how to convert a rather simple influxql query to influxdb2 flux but I just can’t find the correct way. This is the query:

```
SELECT NON_NEGATIVE_DERIVATIVE(MEAN(transmit), 10s) as transmit, NON_NEGATIVE_DERIVATIVE(MEAN(receive), 10s) as receive
FROM nics
WHERE (host = ‘somethost’)
AND time >= ‘3600s’
GROUP BY time(600s), host fill(none)
```

Can someone help me with this conversion?